# Displaying image In Bootstrap card

Tags: html, asp.net, angular

I have Asp.Net Core Web API in backend and Angular in frontend. A user writes a story about couple of images and these images are saved/located in a static folder "assets" in angular.

Now my problem is articles are pulling from the Backend API and images are in frontend assets folder. How can I loop into the assets/images folder to pull a specific image based on story written.

Let me show  client side html code:-

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 ml-0" *ngFor="let t of TravelBlogs">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src="assets/images/mount.jpg" alt="Urgen">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">{{t.title}}</h4>
                    <h4 class="card-text text-muted"> {{t.postCreatedDate | date}}</h4>
                    <h4 class="card-text">{{t.Name}}</h4>
                    <p class="card-text"> {{t.description | truncatetext:100}}
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">read more..</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>       
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should save the image name to backend so you can get the fetch the image from local easily

Comment: Actually, I don't want to save any images or even name in the database, there would be hundred of images going into that specific folder, therefore code suggested below would not serve  the purpose, because it would increase payload exponentially in the future. I wish there should be other way round to solve this problem in the client side coding, where i can bind these images in a variable and loop through it to get the specific image/images from a specific folder based on story... I hope this make sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<md-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="250px">
  <md-grid-tile *ngFor="let model of models">
    <img src="assets/{{model.name}}.png" alt="model {{model.name}}">
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```